# JWT: Multi client auth server, stopping the use of jwt's between different clients?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

Can anyone help ?

I have a multi client auth server, its job is to create JWTs for a specific client (client being a service or app). Each client (service) has a clientID and ClientSecret.

The auth server signs all JWTs with the same token secret. I want to stop a JWT being used from system A on system B - for example. Technically all JWTs are signed with the same secret so this is potential problem.

I was wondering if I can tap into audience and issuer ?

The issuer would be the auth server, right ? So for both different tokens then the issuer would be the same - so this is probably not what I am looking for.

The other thing is audience, could I use this to identify where who the JWT belongs to - ie.. System A or System B - this means I could know weather one is trying to be used on the other and deny it.

I don't know if this is the best way ? Also the format of the audience is a string but normally containing the url of the system - is this correct ?

Actually I was planning on using the audience for differentiating between an Access Token and a Refresh Token.

I am a little confused at the best way of implementing this.

I mean, I could just go ahead and create my own custom claim but I though about using the inbuilt ones - if this is their correct use.

Anybody have any experience in this area ?

So the summarize.

A token should be able to be identified if it was given to System A or System B

Also a token should be intentified if its an Access Token or a Refresh Token.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I would use audience (`aud`) for this as the target system.  It can be any string, and the spec doesn't care if it's a URL or not.  You'll just want the servers to enforce matching audiences (most libraries do this by default, but check your documentation).

For refresh vs. access tokens, you have a few choices.

1) use the issuer.  Again this is just a string, so it could be the host + "access" or host + "refresh" and make sure to verify that issuers match what you expect.

2) use a custom claim.  JWTs can contain any kind of JSON, so create a "type" claim or somesuch with "access" vs "refresh" (or only use it for "access" tokens).  You'd have to manually validate

3) sign refresh and access tokens with different keys.  This one means you won't be able to validate the signature of the wrong kind of token, even before you get to claims checking.

There may be more choices than this.